# Confusion on hashing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, hash, time-complexity

[image][image]

I'm confused on why H<sub>i+1</sub> is being subtracted from H<sub>i</sub> to calculate k+i<sup>2</sup>. If H<sub>i</sub> represents i<sup>2</sup> in the equation then how does H<sub>i+1</sub> factor into being k and why is it subtraction rather than addition?

Comment: H_(i+1) = H_i + x. x = H_(i+1) - H_i = (i+1)*(i+1) - i*i = 2*i+1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is like this. In [quadratic probing[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_probing), you search for positions (involving) *H<sub>1</sub>, H<sub>2</sub>, H<sub>3</sub>, ... H<sub>i</sub>, H<sub>i + 1</sub>, ...* in a loop, and you can avoid recalculating *i<sup>2</sup>* for each *i*.

Say you've already calculated *H<sub>i</sub> = k + i<sup>2</sup>*. Then *H<sub>i + 1</sub> = k + (i + 1)<sup>2</sup> = k + i<sup>2</sup> + 2i + 1 = H<sub>i</sub> + 2i + 1*. So, if you already calculated *H<sub>i</sub>*, you just need to add *2i + 1* for *H<sub>i + 1</sub>*.